# Rails Functional Test: How to test Admin::PostsController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, tdd

I have a controller like follows:

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :posts
end


# app/controllers/admin_posts_controller.rb
module Admin
  class PostsController < ApplicationController
  end
end
```

The problem is I don't know where `Admin::PostsControllerTest` goes.

I was expecting something like following works:

```
# test/functional/admin/posts_controller_test.rb
module Admin
  class PostsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  end
end
```

But if I do that I get the following error when I run `rake test:functionals` :

```
RuntimeError: @controller is nil: make sure you set it in your test's setup method.
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You've got the right location.  Try this:

```
class Admin::PostsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  #put your tests here
end
```